# React Hooks setState in useEffect once on ref mount

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
  const [x, setX] = useState();
  const [y, setY] = useState();

  const elementRef = useRef(null);

  // Calculated here based on elementRef (null on initial render, non-null after mount)
  let boundTop;
  let boundRight;
  let boundBottom;
  let boundLeft;

  // Center the stage on mount and ref mount
  useEffect(() => {
    const x = (window.innerWidth / 2) - ((boundRight - boundLeft) / 2);
    const y = (window.innerHeight / 2) - ((boundBottom - boundTop) / 2);
    setX(x);
    setY(y);
  }, [elementRef.current]);
```

This code works fine and as intended - on initial render and ref mount (`[elementRef.current]` dependency array), it will set the state of X and Y to some initial values and then never execute again.

But! The default Hooks ESLint rules nudge me to add the `bound` state variables as dependencies to the `useEffect` dependency array. I don't wanna do that! I don't want those values to change again through this hook after the initial mount.

If I did add the bound values as dependencies to the effect, my canvas could never move, because each move to it (by changing X and Y in response to mouse/touch) would cause a render, thus bounds would be recalculated, the hook dependencies changed, X and Y centered and the original movement of X and Y which caused the canvas to move would become undone.

Is there a pattern to use to code around this ESLint rule?

Comment: do you use boundRight, boundLeft, boundRight, boundBottom anywhere else in your component?

Comment: I do use it outside of the `useEffect` hook as well so I cannot inline it.

Answer (score 2):

The `useState` allows you to set its [initial value](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state) via a callback, so you don't need your `useEffect` at all.

Change your `useState` like so and remove your whole `useEffect`:

```
const [x, setX] = useState(() => (window.innerWidth / 2) - ((boundRight - boundLeft) / 2));
const [y, setY] = useState(() => (window.innerHeight / 2) - ((boundBottom - boundTop) / 2));
```

Comment: Sorry, I initially stated the question wrong. The hook actually depends on a ref, and I've updated the dependency array to show it. So the hook runs on initial render and ref mount. It should not run afterwards though, so still can't depend on the bounds variables.